# Error: Cannot find symbol class Decor bug after updating Android Studio

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I just recently updated Android Studio, and now Android studio is unable to find ViewPager.Decor. I have class called ViewPagerTitleStripV22 which extends ViewPager.Decor. This class i guess was a solution to a bug where the titles were not showing up with the ViewPager.[(link to solution)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32379050/how-can-we-work-around-the-blank-title-in-pagertitlestrip-and-pagertabstrip/37553889?noredirect=1#comment62598263_37553889)This class used to compile fine before I updated android Studio. If I use the regular ViewPagerTitleStrip, The title strip will not show up. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How did you fixed it? I am unable to run due to this exception after updating the Android Studio today.

Comment: Update. I never fixed it. I ran the app using ViewPagerTabStrip instead of ViewPagerTabStrip22, and now the titles are not showing up.